# My Android app crashes when sending input value to another Activity

Tags: android

I am sending  two user input values in the Result_Page where a TextView will show the inputs. But I am getting an error in this line in the Result_Page.  Any tips would be really valuable. Thank you.

```
cl = Double.parseDouble(rd1);
```

xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/btn"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
     android:text="Done" />

 <EditText
     android:id="@+id/editText2"
     android:layout_width="155dp"
     android:layout_height="40dp"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
     android:hint="Fill percentage"
     android:ems="10"
     android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

 <EditText
     android:id="@+id/editText1"
     android:layout_width="155dp"
     android:layout_height="40dp"
     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
     android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btn"
     android:ems="10"
     android:hint="Fill centilitre"
     android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Info

```
//not publishing the imports here
public class Info extends Activity {
EditText editText1, editText2;
Button btn;
private String rd1, rd2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_info);
    initCommonGui();
    initListeners();
}

public void initCommonGui() {
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    editTextProsent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
}

private void initListeners() {

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (editText1.equals(null)) {
                Log.i("nana", "do nothing");

            } else {
                rd1 = editText1.getText().toString().trim();
            }

            if (editText2.equals(null)) {
                Log.i("nana", "do nothing");
            } else {
                rd2 = editText2.getText().toString().trim();
            }
            if (!editText1.equals(null) && !editText2.equals(null)) {
                otherActivity("result");
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Fill in the blanks !",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });

}


public void otherActivity(String a) {
    Intent i = new Intent();
    if (a.equals("result")) {

        i.putExtra("rd1", rd1);
        i.putExtra("rd2", rd2);

        i.setClass(getApplicationContext(), Result_Page.class);
    }
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}

}
```

Result_Page

```
 public class Result_Page extends Activity {
TextView  result;
String rd1, rd2;
private float percentage;
double cl;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);

    Intent intent = getIntent(); 

    rd1 = intent.getStringExtra("rd1");
    rd2 = intent.getStringExtra("rd2");
            cl = Double.parseDouble(rd1); 
            percentage = Float.parseFloat(rd2);
result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
result.setText(" " + cl + " " + percentage);
}
}
```

Comment: I guess you are passing string value or an empty string instead of a number in rd1.

Comment: Seems like your rd1 is not a valid `double` value. Log the value before sending

Comment: please place a log output printing rd1 and rd2 after the get string extra lines.

Comment: what to do if I dont want to pass the empty string ?

Comment: try to pass zero value when the string is empty

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the `String` you are passing may be its Empty, it is not **convertible** to `Double`

So `Handle` `NumberFormatException`  `Exception` this like below

```
try {
        cl  = Double.parseDouble(rd1);
        System.out.println("Double Value is " + " " +c1);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        nfe.printStackTrace();
        }
```

First check `weather String is Empty or not`

```
public static boolean isNullOrEmpty(String value) {
        return value == null || value.length() == 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Before passing the values convert them to Double if String is not null. If String is null pass 0.0 or something like that.